# Hadoop YARN 2.2.0 "Text File Busy Errors"

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, centos, hadoop-yarn

I am running a single node Hadoop 2.2.0 YARN  cluster on CentOS 6.4 ec2 AMI and when I submit the job I get the following error which appears to be occuring when a container is being launched . Can someone please let me know how to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

```
Exception from container-launch: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: /bin/bash: /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1393311978074_0011/container_1393311978074_0011_01_000003/launch_container.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there seems to be bug fix for the issue, check it out. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1271

Comment: Yes, I saw that JIRA issue , but it does not give me any info as to how to resolve it , I have downloaded the latest Hadoop2.2.0 distribution , what else do I need to do to get this bug fix ? Thanks.

Comment: There are links to patches for your version on that page . You should apply them by your self(download source, download and apply patch and finally build patched source), or get a nightly built of that version. If you do not know how to apply a patch, you can find many pages by searching at google.

Comment: @user1965449  Hadoop 2.2.0 is the latest version. You said you upgraded version of hadoop. What version did you upgrade hadoop to?
I too am having the same problem